# a typescript code confusing me

Tags: typescript2.0

There is a question confusing me so much。
The tutorial on the site（http://www.typescriptlang.org）introduces the grammar  as follows:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/3t4ui.png

It means that {name:”Alice”} is the subtype of {name:”Alice”,location:”seattle”}( obviously,has excess property)，but the typescript document tells us as follow:
"S is a subtype of a type T, and T is a supertype of S, if S has no excess properties with respect to T"

Comment: I am not sure that you completed your question. Would you care to elaborate more?

Comment: this is my first visit to this site,
so sorry

Comment: Why can't mesend two links?

Comment: completed  now ,could you help me

Comment: I believe what is telling you is that the object y must be of the same type as the object x. This is a more specific example of the differences.

Comment: ya，is there something wrong with the sentence "The type system enforces that the source function’s return type be a subtype of the target type’s return type." 。I think the y is not the subtype of x（y has excess property） ，because the typeScript document say that "S is a subtype of a type T, and T is a supertype of S, if S has no excess properties with respect to T"

Answer (score 0):

I believe what it is telling you is that the object y must be of the same type as the object x or at least a sub-type. x is part of y, but not the other way around. This is a more specific example of the differences using classes instead of objects,

```
class x {
constructor(public name: string){}
}

class y extends x {
constructor(public name: string, public location: string){
    super(name);
}
}

let myX: x = y; // OK
let myY: y = x; // Error:  "Type 'typeof x' is not assignable to type 'y'. Property 'location' is missing in type 'typeof x'. let myY: y"
```

// PLUG this code in the typescript playground to see it work, or not... :)

Comment: first thank you very much，i agree with you ；I just guess there is something wrong with the sentence  "The type system enforces that the source function’s return type be a subtype of the target type’s return type." 。I think the y is not the subtype of x（y has excess property） ，because the typeScript document say that "S is a subtype of a type T, and T is a supertype of S, if S has no excess properties with respect to T"